# Issue using glReadPixels result

Tags: c++, opengl, glreadpixels

For a homework assignment, I need to implement a floodfill algorithm. My code is already structured, but I can't seem to figure out why my glReadPixels section isn't working. I was hoping someone could take a look at what I'm doing and let me know if I'm incorrect in its usage.

```
// I fetch pixels like so:
    glReadPixels(100, 250, 150, 150, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, clip_pixels);
// I index the result using:
    in_rect_pos = (in_rect_y * in_rect_w) + in_rect_x;
    // in_rect_* is a point w/ its origin at (100, 250)
    GLubyte *pixel_at_pos = clip_pixels + (in_rect_pos * GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT);
```

But I'm not getting the correct values, and I really don't even know how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot one very significant mistake in your code:

```
GLubyte *pixel_at_pos = clip_pixels + (in_rect_pos * GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT);
```

Using `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` here is wrong in two different ways:

1. Fundamentally, `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is an *enum* value in OpenGL. It happens to be defined to 0x0D05 (3333 in decimal), and it is not the *value* of the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` GL state, which you can set via [`glPixelStore`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml) and query back via [`glGet`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGet.xml). In both cases, `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is just used to reference which GL state variable is to be accessed.
2. You do not use the alignment correctly. Even if you had used the value queried by `glGetIntegerv(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, &alignment)`, your formula would still be wrong. The `GL_PIXEL_PACK` alignment reference the adresses of each *row* of pixel data. By default, it is set to 4, so if your row would not start at an address divisible by 4, you have to add 1 to 3 padding bytes to make it divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int X = 0;
const int Y = 0;
const int Width = 100;
const int Height = 100;

unsigned char Buffer[Width * Height * 3];
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(X, Y, Width, Height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &Buffer[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        unsigned char R = Buffer[(i * j + width) + 0];
        unsigned char G = Buffer[(i * j + width) + 1];
        unsigned char B = Buffer[(i * j + width) + 2];
    }
}
```

If it is aligned on some boundary (and you don't do: `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`), you will need to account for padding..

Example:

```
unsigned char* ptr = &Buffer[0];

for (int i = 0; i < Height; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Width; ++j)
    {
        int R = *(ptr++);
        int G = *(ptr++);
        int B = *(ptr++);
    }

    ptr += (4 - ((width * 3) % 4)) % 4; //DWORD boundary alignment.
}
```